# C++ - Proper way to add<T> obiect to std::vector<abstract C> in template method without copy T

Tags: c++, templates, stdvector, unique-ptr, stdmap

A program has an interface called Component:

```
class Component
{
public:
    virtual void Start() = 0;
    virtual void Update() = 0;
};
```

This interface is implemented by MeshComponent:

.h

```
#include "Component.h"
#include "Mesh.h"

class MeshComponent: public Component
{
public:
    Mesh* mesh;
    int a = 0; // for test
    MeshComponent();
    
    void Start();
    void Update();
};
```

.cpp

```
#include "MeshComponent.h"

MeshComponent::MeshComponent(): mesh(nullptr)
{
}

void MeshComponent::Start()
{
    std::cout << this << " " << a << "Start Mesh component\n";
}

void MeshComponent::Update()
{}
```

And it used in Object:

```
#include "Mesh.h"
#include "Vector3.h"
#include "Component.h"
class Object
{
private:
    void bindPosition();

    void updateComponents();

    std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Component>>> components;

public:
    Vector3 position;
    Object();
    ~Object();

    // T:Component
    template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Component, T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
    void addComponent(T component) {
        Component* comp = ((Component*)&component);
        std::string name(typeid(T).name());
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Component>>& arr = components[name];
        arr.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Component>(comp));
        T& c = (T&)*arr.back();
        c.Start();
    }
};
```

Like you see I use std::map<std::string, std::vectorstd::unique_ptr<Component>> to contain components. It is because I want to use something like this:

```
parent.getComponent<Movement>(); // first one
parent.getComponents<Material>(); // array
```

Every component have to be unique - that's why it is copied and I want user to know it is copied. I don't want copy it twice so I thought of using unique_ptr.

I want to avoid using destructor when I deleta Object. That's why I avoid pointers.
I also want to avoid using move schematic.

If you read this code you probably see my mistake that's the 'T component' is deleted when it is out of scope (I found it by writing this question. This was the main reason for this question).

I want you ask for advice, how should I do it properly. By looking at it I think I do unnecessary transformations that can be avoided (working with abstract class is hell) or the way to contain components is wrong.

I'm counting on you.

Comment: const ref is not enough?

Comment: What do you mean by const reference? 'const T component'? I am not familiar with C++.

Comment: if you pass a parameter by const ref, you won't get a copy out of the parameter, so `const T& component`

Comment: Your `addComponent()` takes its `component` parameter *by value* and then stores a `std::unique_ptr<Component>` pointer to that object into your `components` map. That will not end well. After `addComponent()` exits, the pointer will be left dangling. And worse, the object wasn't even created with `new` to begin with, so the `unique_ptr` will fail when it tries to destroy the object.

Comment: But I want it to be copied, because user who will call this method will knows that the component is copied. For example I created component and set value, for example speed. And now I create 1000 objects with this component. Now I want change speed only for one object. I can't because I have const ref.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Component, T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void addComponent(T component) {
    Component* comp = ((Component*)&component);
    // ...
    arr.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Component>(comp));
    // ...
}
```

Yeah you cannot do that. The proper way would be to copy it into a new unique pointer:

```
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Component, T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void addComponent(T component) {
    // ...
    arr.push_back(std::make_unique<T>(comp));
    // ...
}
```

As you said though you don't want two copies, so you can take your argument by const reference:

```
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Component, T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void addComponent(T const& component) {
    // ...
    arr.push_back(std::make_unique<T>(comp));
    // ...
}
```

You can also add an overload to move the object if you send in an rvalue, making it zero copy when possible:

```
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Component, T>::value
                                          && !std::is_reference<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void addComponent(T&& component) {
    // ...
    arr.push_back(std::make_unique<T>(std::move(comp)));
    // ...
}
```

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<Component>(new T{comp})` would be better handled using `std::make_unique<T>(comp)` instead.  `std::unique_ptr<Component>` should be able to move a `std::unique_ptr<T>` as long as `T*` is implicitly convertible to `Component*`

Comment: I want make it clear for user that the component is copied. Becouse of that I didn't use T& component as parameter. Is the secound solutions clearly said "I want you to be copied". I want make it "lazy" to use without using copy constructor or move constructor (only default is needed) in implementation of Component interface.

Comment: Do I exaggerate with that

Comment: @Apsik I'd say having a sink function like that is clear enough. Just like `vector.push_back(...)` you know you copy the element into a vector, yet it takes its argument by reference.

Comment: You are right. My first thought when developing this method was: if I use T without * or & I just copy it and I want it to be copy it's clear functionality (I don't need to read the documentation to know this, it is copied).

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot last question how can I use `std::make_unique<Component>` on abstract class

Comment: @Apsik That can't work. If you want to polymorphically copy an object, you should implement a `virtual std::unique_ptr<Component> clone() = 0;` member function.